# How to sort a dataset by partial search within a row's title in pandas/python

Tags: python, string, pandas, sorting, dataset

I have a large dataset which can be sorted by its description only. The description describes the product by naming it like: ProductVariantSpesification. I want to sort out the Variant and create new datasets including only those who have the same Variant.

I tried:

```
400_variants = df[df[Description].str.contains("400")]
```

How it would look like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'raw_data.xlsx', header = 0)

#Some code

df.to_excel(r'400.xlsx')
```

I'm starting out with something like this:

```
Index   Description Quantity    Date
1   Ketchup400J 5   5/10/2019
2   Ketchup600J 4   5/11/2019
3   Ketchup800U 6   5/12/2019
4   Ketchup400U 7   5/13/2019
5   Ketchup600J 8   5/14/2019
6   Ketchup400U 9   5/15/2019
7   Ketchup800i 5   5/16/2019
8   …   …   …
```

And want the output for the 400 variant to be:

```
Index   Description Quantity    Date
1   Ketchup400J 5   5/10/2019
2   Ketchup400U 7   5/13/2019
3   Ketchup400U 9   5/15/2019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with `str.findall` and with `groupby`

```
for x , y in df.groupby(df.Description.str.findall(r'[0-9]+').str[0]):
    print(y)
    y.to_excel(str(x)+'.xlsx')

   Index  Description  Quantity       Date
0      1  Ketchup400J         5  5/10/2019
3      4  Ketchup400U         7  5/13/2019
5      6  Ketchup400U         9  5/15/2019
   Index  Description  Quantity       Date
1      2  Ketchup600J         4  5/11/2019
4      5  Ketchup600J         8  5/14/2019
   Index  Description  Quantity       Date
2      3  Ketchup800U         6  5/12/2019
6      7  Ketchup800i         5  5/16/2019
```

---

Update

```
d={x : y for  x , y in df.groupby(df.Description.str.findall(r'[0-9]+').str[0])}
d['400']
```

Comment: Would it be possible to reset the index for the new lists?

Comment: @aosa adding `y.reset_index(drop=True).to_excel(str(x)+'.xlsx')`

Comment: thanks! How can i then retrieve one of the lists after the for loop?

Comment: @aosa I am not sure what you mean ,would like open a new question about it ?

Comment: I would like to use the different lists of y later on in the code. a easy command after the for loop could be print(y[400]) or df2 = y[600]....

Answer (score 0):

Try `str.contains`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Description':['Ketchup400J', 'Ketchup400K', 'Mustard400J', 'Ketchup300K','Mustard300K'],'Quantity':range(5),'Date':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2019',periods=5, freq='D')})
>>> df
   Description  Quantity       Date
0  Ketchup400J         0 2019-01-01
1  Ketchup400K         1 2019-01-02
2  Mustard400J         2 2019-01-03
3  Ketchup300K         3 2019-01-04
4  Mustard300K         4 2019-01-05

>>> df[df.Description.str.contains('400')]
   Description  Quantity       Date
0  Ketchup400J         0 2019-01-01
1  Ketchup400K         1 2019-01-02
2  Mustard400J         2 2019-01-03
```